# What's the best way to make a dynamic slideshow using angular

Tags: angularjs

What's the best way to create a dynamic slideshow using angular 1.3? I would like to build one, I was trying with http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ but it doesn't work when use angular.js at the same page.

```
<div ng-repeat="diaporama in diaporamas" class="cycle-slideshow">
     <img class="diaporama-img" src='{{diaporama.photo_file_name | image_diaporama_path_format: diaporama.id}}'/>
</div>

<script>
   $(".cycle-slideshow").cycle();
</script>
```

Comment: would work if you put it in a directive so elements exist when code runs

Answer (score 1):

I believe in order to achieve what you desire you'll be looking to create a directive for that purpose.

A good start would be referring to angulars documentation on [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for response, I'll try to use directives.